# Then not getting executed

Tags: reactjs, promise, keycloak

I added the following code to the click event handler-

```
onClick={() => {

          alert("User trying to log in");
          const keycloak = Keycloak({
            realm: "***",
            url: "https://*****/auth/",
            clientId: "****",
          });
          keycloak
            .init({ onLoad: "login-required" })
            .then((authenticated) => {
              if (authenticated) {
                alert("Authernicated");
                alert(JSON.stringify(keycloak));


                // setTimeout(5000)
                keycloak.loadUserInfo().then((userInfo) => {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
                });
                
              } else {
                alert("not");
              }
            });
            
        }}
```

The logic within then doesn’t get executed on clicking for the first time .

After clicking the second time only I see the alerts.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: On first click, either (1) there's a synchronous error eg in the construction of `keycloak`, (2)`keycloak.init()` returns a Promise that takes its error path, or (3) `authenticated` is falsy. Find out which, then you might be able to answer the question.

Comment: Should be `keycloak = new Keycloak({...});`. `new` is unlikely to make a difference here but can do so under some circumstances.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `keycloak.loadUserProfile()`?